# How do I make infinite lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make an infinite lava source,like with the water. If one puts 2 blocks of water,they will fill another block completely. Lava does not do exactly the same. If this is not possible,lava is limited,not like water. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> If this is not possible,lava is limited, not like water.

This is correct. You cannot generate lava in vanilla minecraft without using commands, or creative mode.

However, although lava *is* limited, it is found in massive quantities in the [Nether](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether). So it is theoretically possible to transfer all the lava you want to your world, albeit long and boring.

Answer (score 0):

You can't lava is not an infinite resource (barring going through infinite chunks).

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lava